# On divisive cults/religion

Tags: magic, government, religion, fantasy-races

Alright, in my fantasy world of munda I am having trouble with a specific sect of Gnomes. Most gnomes are wiry playful, jubilant and scared of outsiders. But in the land of Thel (where all traditional Fey originate) there is a specific cult of gnomes that directly opposes the other gnomes. While other gnomes hide, the cult of the red cap does nothing to hide themselves, and even wears brightly colored  red caps that stick out like a sore thumb in the mushroom forests they live in. They are also one of the few gnome people that live in groups and not solitary which means their government and customs must echo this.

My question lies here. What sort of culture would one have that worships fate and destiny? One that believes whatever happens is what was meant to happen and nothing could change that? How would they worship? How would they defend themselves? Are there any real life echos of something like this?

Edit: so moirae would be the gods, but this is more a culture of such people. I already have the gods themselves but the worship and people who do this are more the topic.

Comment: Islam fits this, so do the Greek [Moirae LINK](http://www.theoi.com/Daimon/Moirai.html)  

Islam is easy to research.

Comment: Just kind of curious but what does their opposition of other gnome life have to do with the question?  Are you implying that their religion makes them the way they are?

Comment: @ggiaquin yes. Their religion is direct opposition to the nature of gnomes, like I said, gnomes are naturally skiddish.

Comment: A [very long time ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-Iranian_language) the ancestors of the Iranians and of the [Indo-Aryans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-Aryan_languages) were one people. In their language the word  _devá_ meant a divine being. But then they split, and in Sanskrit (spoken in the east) [_deva_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devi) means a god, while in Avestan (spoken in the west) [_daeva_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daeva) means a demon.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Munda. Please note that asking multiple questions is generally discouraged, as it can lead to excessively long answers. That being said, questions about culture tend to be difficult due to the factors of a culture being good or bad is largely subjective. Thus, each answer could produce a different, equally valid culture.

Comment: I'm not sure of the specifics, but I imagine they would clearly worship using very specific rituals, carrying out exactly the ordained task repeatedly.

Comment: Would they even worship? If fate is determined no matter what, worship won't fix it or improve the situation.

Comment: @frosrfyre it's not really multiple questions in my mind. Culture and religion are near synonymous in most cases I've seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well odiously your culture would be very fatalistic. If there not try to hind themselves from then I see to possible cultures that might spring from this fatalistic belief.

1. Passive application of there faith: Since no man can escape his fate and there is no point in hide then is there is also no point it fighting. Afteral if the outcome is already decided then will we either or we won't either wiway it is out of our control.
2. Aggressive application of there faith: If there is no free will and our ends is already decided then why not send our time here killing our enemies instead of hiding. If we go int battle and we die then that was are fate and would have happened anyways, If we live then that was our fate.

Either way I would imagine that your society would be very class biased with very little momentum. After all if your born into a certain class then that must be your fate. They all so would be reluctant to help others after all some people are just fated for hardship.

Something to keep in mind is a. Very few religions are homogenizes, because people often take the same set of believes and apply them in completely different ways so you might  see 1 and 2 red hood Gnomes.

b. contrary to what Fayth85 says you can become a dominate religion without "'heretical witch-hunts' to 'purify' the flock" or even a Theocratic government.

Comment: Thanks, this was a bit more helpful. I think I can try and combine one and two. The class bias is especially helpful. I never thought of that. They probably wouldn't use much magic, or even try to advance their society. Thanks, this was more helpful to my original bias.

Comment: Was about to say fatalism. Nice vocab word

Answer (score 3):

WARNING! Some very acidic notions ahead! If you are easily offended, please do not read.

It doesn't matter what cult, religion, or philosophy you pick for the sociological background noise. Sure, I could go through a list of real-world religions and cults that fit the bill (Hindoism, and the belief in Karma, Christianity and 'God's divine plan') but most of them use circular logic to 'prove' they are actual and factual.

## It boils down to control.

Why control? Well, because if any one of those gnomes takes a step back and analyses their deeply held beliefs? They will find that they do have a choice. So, expect a LOT of 'heretical witch-hunts' to 'purify' the flock.

Let me give an example.

Meet David, the gnome. He is a veterinarian working with wounded animals in his neck of the woods. He sees many animals being hurt either by hunting (wild animals tend to do that), or poacher traps (stupid humans!). He is faced with a choice every time he encounters human. Does he help the animal (as he is wont to do)? Or does he hide and sacrifice this one for the hundreds he could help if the humans do not spot him?

I'm sure your Red Hood gnomes will tell him, "That is fate! It's destined to happen! So why fight it?" And maybe this is arguably true, from a certain perspective. But David knows that if he does nothing, the animals will die. He refuses to believe that this 'fate' the Red Hoods would leave others to suffer is the 'right thing to do'.

So how does this affect your Red Hoods? Well. There would be a dominant religious group. Perhaps their 'nation' is a [Theocracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theocracy). There would be those with power among them, and they would have the power to 'dictate' the will of the god(s) they serve; unless there really is/are god(s) that dictate their fate and the rules to which they must adhere ([fates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fates), and the like).

This is where choices start coming in. Those in power, how precious is that power to them? If the answer is 'everything', or that the god's will is absolute, then expect severe repercussions. After all, you aren't risking my anger, but the righteous indignation of a being so powerful that our way of life might well hang in the balance if you upset said god with your ignorant insolence.

If the consensus is more mild, "live and let live", then expect little to happen. Perhaps something as simple as a 'request' to vacate the community, "lest you poison the minds of the young and impressionable". As I said, it's about control.

It might be interesting if another group comes about to counter this notion. But that is up to the 'powers that be'.

Comment: I like the angle which you came at the answer.  I was struggling on the fact  that OP seemed to jump from setting up a cultural question about life style to asking what religion is based on fate.

Comment: @ggiaquin thanks ^_^ I love trying to offer an angle most wouldn't think of

Comment: Because their religion makes them whom they are, unlike most they splintered off only due to their religion. And as all gods are real in this setting, they will be correct. If you are a history major you will see the culture is formed around the religion. If you think one doesn't affect the other you would be mistaken.

Comment: @Fayth85: your answer assumes their religion is false. I suppose I should have added that all religions are true. The heretics angle is being played elsewhere and I'd hate to recycle for every religion. As they speak with their gods heretics will be rare.

Comment: @Munda don't need to get all high and mighty, no I am not a history major.  I have a real degree in software development.  Your question lacked correlation between the 2 as it just assumed everyone would know that is what you meant.  It also lacked logical flow and you did nothing to tie the 2 together.  Write better questions and you will get better answers.

Comment: @Munda Historically you are being imprecise. Religion started off as a sub-class of politics, that is to control the people. Look at the Middle East in biblical and pre-biblical times. The temples were a means of getting people to come together so that the leaders could measure their loyalty to the state supported religion, and mete out any updates they needed the people to believe. That's why Israel demolished their temples and maintained only 'the one, true temple of god', to force everyone of their kingdom to come to Jerusalem.

Comment: Furthermore, if you look into the archaeological and historical studies done in that direction, you'll find that most of what we now consider 'cannon' in the bible is what was then used as propaganda to rile up the people of Israel to strike at Babylon, who was their main threat of the day. Don't like it? That's okay. But then you should have heeded my warning in the first line of my answer.

Comment: @Fayth85 Im going to add a bit of meta-commentary here in an effort to keep the conversation productive:  Asserting how religion started is beyond our current knowledge of history. We have some theories, but there are several competing/contradictory theories that fit data. Yours is one of them, but not the only. Please be careful not to overstate your case... that leads to flame wars.

Comment: @Fayth85 again, you act as though religion didn't create culture. Tell me, is Jewish a religion, culture, tribe, or ethnic group? All the answers are correct and incorrect. You also presume far too much. We can hardly say if belief in say, Yahweh, was created before the culture or post culturally, or politically. You presume you know far more than is humanly possible.

Comment: @ggiaquin my apology if you thought I was acting haughty, it wasn't my intention.

Comment: @Munda if you want me to cite sources and explain my standpoint, I'd be happy to. However that would mean stepping over to chat, seeing as this is getting too lengthy for comments. Suffice (imo) to say, I've been studying the history and theory behind religion for years. It's fascinating. I'm not hypothesising that there isn't a feedback loop between culture and religion, I am merely stating that religion has been most commonly know to be used as a tool of control. Google 'The Bible Unearthed' for some interesting facts as was researched by a biblical scholar and archaeologist.

Comment: @Munda One last thing: religion doesn't make you who you are. Culture, upbringing, and predetermined genetic markers make you who you are. Religion is merely a lens, a filter, through which one can interpret the world around you. Example: Christians A and B. Christian A is rich, well educated, affluent, and charismatic. Denied nothing during upbringing, always a 'model Christian'. Christian B is poor, so busy working two jobs that there isn't time to study, and irritable from being tired all the time. Goes to church only on holidays, and was a criminal during youth. The only unifying factor?

Comment: @Fayth obviously. But now you are confusing individuality and culture, which are utterly different things.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the means to change something, obviously, fate has given you that gift, therefore it is fate that you will.

There is a large difference between:

whatever happens is what *was* meant to happen

AND

don't do anything because you can't change it.

If something has already happened, then it was destiny and fate. If someone betrayed you in the past, then they were meant to be the betrayer, just as you are meant to punish that betrayal. It is your fate to do so.

A person from this culture could be impassive when they punish that betrayal (because everyone only has their parts to play--it is not the fault of the betrayer anymore than it is your fault that you must punish them). Or they could feel superior and chosen by fate to cleanse the world, in a righteous anger. The betrayer should be punished--they are unclean and were made that way by fate.

That's just one example, but as you can see, this is pretty broad and opinion-based. You could get two diametrically opposed reactions to betrayal from the same thing. Or a third option--you can say you are fated to give the betrayer a 2nd chance. It is your decision as the betrayed. His fate is in your hands, given to you by destiny.